# Rails API upload image with refile and s3 using json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, amazon-s3, refile

I need to upload image to `s3` using `refile` gem with `Rails-API` via. `json` I follow refile guide on how to setup refile with S3 and when I test it with curl the POST request get created successfully but the image did not upload.

*Request json data:*

```
{
  "picture": {
    "image":"@bin/test.jpg;type=image/jpeg",
    "imageable_id":"1",
    "imageable_type":"Product"
  }
}
```

*Curl request:*

```
# curl_post file
create() {
  curl -v -X POST \
     -H 'Accept: application/json' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d @bin/product.json \
     http://localhost:3000/api/pictures
}

$1
```

*The console log:*

```
Started POST "/api/pictures" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-26 23:04:03 +0200
Processing by Api::PicturesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"picture"=>{"image"=>"@bin/test.jpg;type=image/jpeg", "imageable_id"=>"1", "imageable_type"=>"Product"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "pictures" ("image_id", "imageable_type", "imageable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["image_id", nil], ["imageable_type", "Product"], ["imageable_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-02-26 21:04:03.444481"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-26 21:04:03.444481"]]
   (33.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 39ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 34.0ms)
```

Comment: Having similar issue. How did you solved it?

Comment: @waqarmirza yes https://github.com/adham90/massdrop-rails-ember/tree/feature/test/api